# requests.post return HTTP 200 python

Tags: python, python-2.7, rest

Following [getdrip api docs](https://www.getdrip.com/docs/rest-api#create_or_update_subscriber). I am trying to create new subscriber using `POST`.
But `requests.post` returns 200 not 201.

my code,

```
>>> import requests
>>> url = 'http://api.getdrip.com/v2/<id_here>/subscribers'
>>> payload = {'email': 'nishant@gmail.com', 'custom_fields': {'name':'Nishant'}}
>>> headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer TOKEN_VALUE','Content-Type':'application/vnd.api+json'}
>>> requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
/home/nishant/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
<Response [200]>
>>>
```

Whats wrong I did here ?

Comment: Try `https://` in the URL.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks that worked.

Comment: Excellent. It's worthwhile reading the info at the URL in that warning message, though. [InsecurePlatformWarning](https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning)

Comment: @PM2Ring haha my mistake. Will remember it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documents says:

> This document outlines the official specification for the Drip RESTful API. This API communicates exclusively in JSON over SSL (`HTTPS`). All endpoint URLs begin with https://api.getdrip.com/v2/.